# Truncate short day names in variable

Tags: shell, busybox

I have a variable with short day names, it can be in any order, with less or more week days, always comma separated like this:

```
days='Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun'
```

How can I cut the last letter from each to this:

```
days='Tu,We,Th,Fr,Sa,Su'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
days="${days},"           # adds trailing comma
days="${days//?,/,}"      # changes every character+comma to sole comma
days="${days%,}"          # removes trailing comma
```

Alternatively

```
days="${days//?,/,}"      # changes every character+comma to sole comma
days="${days%?}"          # removes last character
```

I can't find the syntax `${parameter/pattern/string}` in POSIX documentation; I guess it may or may not work, depending on how rich your shell is. Still in my tests in few systems with `busybox` and/or `sh` the syntax was supported.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful and works as is in BusyBox, I tried it with `cut` and `sed` but that was ugly code.
For those wanting to cut even more, use additional question marks in `${days//?,/,}`.